# outer p:selectCheckBoxMenu visible from composite p:dialog

Tags: primefaces, composite

I have the following scenario :

- **Page.xhtml** (p:selectCheckBoxMenu **id=sb1**)

  1. From page.xhtml I call genericDialog.xhtml
- **genericDialog.xhtml** (Composite implementation with p:dialog,etc...)

  2. From genericDialog.xhtml how can I process and update via p:ajax the **sb1** component.

*Error :  javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "formPessoa:tipoMercado" referenced from "j_idt440:myForm:confirm"*

[image]

- From the left side of image in green color I have my composite p:dialog (**genericDialog.xhtml**)
- From the right side of image  I have in red the selectCheckBoxMenu id=**sb1** which I need to reload after saving new data from dialog.

thanks a lot stack members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time to me.... I figured out the issue:

```
<p:commandButton id="confirm" value="#{cc.attrs.labelbotao1}" 
   oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncompletebotao1}" update="myForm:divmessage" 
   actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionbeanbotao1}" **ajax="true"**>

   <p:ajax update="#{cc.attrs.ajaxupdate1}" process="#{cc.attrs.ajaxprocess1}" 
   listener="#{cc.attrs.listener1}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

**Two problems:**

- First I need to reference in the composition genericDialog.xhtml the full path to update the component e.g. myform: sb1
- Second the AJAX on p: commandButton has to be false. This way it does not cancel the p: AJAX update and process.

I'd like to hear some other opinions or fixes, etc.